# Document.save() doesn't work for ref arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document that contains

`events: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event'}]`

field, yet whenever I execute

```
user.save(req.body).then(function (user) {
    res.json(user);
});
```

user.events is not saved properly and remains an empty array.

I've even tried doing this prior to `save()`:

```
if(req.body.events)
    req.body.events = req.body.events.map(function(id){
        return mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(id);
    });
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "Schema" in your model.
Try this:

```
events: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event'}]
```

EDIT:
There are a few other things you might want to check in order to make this work:

(1)Make sure that you are grabbing the user you want to update.

(2)Double-check the syntax using this page of the documentation.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html

It looks like your req.body is in a wrong place.  You also do not want to use ".then" here. 
In your example, I would put it like this:

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) { 
//Grab the user you want to update from the database.
  if (err) return handleError(err);
//This is an extra tip, but use error handlers so you can detect errors.

  user.events = req.body.events;
//Here you are updating the user info that you grabbed from the database.
  user.save(function(err) {
//Saves the updated user info to the database. 
  if(err) return handleError(err);
  res.send(user); 
  });
});
```

However, I use "findByIdAndUpdate" or "update" (both are on the documentation link I provided) than the above because it is more concise.